# Get attachments but only from post gallery?

Tags: gallery

I can get post attachment images it is ok. But i want to get attachments from only post's gallery? Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
global $post;
$id = $post->ID;
$post = get_post($post);
$images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=DESC&post_parent='.$post->post_parent);
```

Comment: Posts can have multiple galleries, and each can be customized to display different images. They're added directly to the post HTML content via a [gallery] shortcode and aren't recorded anywhere else. So, there's no programmatic way to get attachments from a gallery in a post.

Comment: You could search the content for a gallery shortcode, parse the IDs then request each image separately.  I'm sure you don't want to do that, but you could.

Comment: Is there only one gallery per post or more of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the [`[gallery]` shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode), then you can use the [`get_post_gallery()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery) or [`get_post_galleries()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_galleries) function to retrieve the gallery *data* such as `ids` (a list of IDs separated with comma) and `src` (an `array` of image URLs).

### Sample code #1: (using `get_post_gallery()`)

`1234` is the ID of the post containing the `[gallery]` shortcode.

```
$galry = get_post_gallery( 1234, false );
$images = [];
if ( $galry && isset( $galry['ids'] ) ) {
    $ids = wp_parse_id_list( $galry['ids'] );
    $images = get_posts( [
        'post__in'  => $ids,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    ] );
    echo 'Number of images in gallery #1:<br>';
    echo count( $images ) . '<br>';
}
```

### Sample code #2: (using `get_post_galleries()`)

`1234` is the ID of the post containing the `[gallery]` shortcode**s**.

```
$galrys = get_post_galleries( 1234, false );
foreach ( $galrys as $i => $galry ) {
    $ids = wp_parse_id_list( $galry['ids'] );
    $images = get_posts( [
        'post__in'  => $ids,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    ] );
    echo 'Number of images in gallery #' . ( $i + 1 ) . ':<br>';
    echo count( $images ) . '<br>';
}
```

So:

- Use `get_post_galleries()` to retrieve the data of *all* `[gallery]` shortcodes in the post content.
- Use `get_post_gallery()` to retrieve the data of the *first* `[gallery]` shortcode in the post content.